# why SelectionKey.attachment() is null?

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel

Here's the main part of server code:

```
Selector selector = Selector.open();
ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port));
serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
serverSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

while (true) {
    selector.select();
    Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
    for (var iter = keys.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
       SelectionKey key = iter.next(); iter.remove();
          if (key.isValid()) {
              if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                  register(key);
              }
              else if (key.isReadable()) {
                  readBytes(key);
              }
              else if (key.isWritable()) {
                  sendResponse(key);
              }
          }
    }

}

private void register(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    var ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
    var client = ssc.accept();
    client.configureBlocking(false);
    client.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    key.attach(new ClientData());
}
private void readBytes(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    var data = (ClientData) key.attachment();
    client.read(data.buffer);
    client.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
}
```

ClientData:

```
public class ClientData {
    public final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
}
```

I except from this that the server will read all the client’s bytes and put it in its attachment. But when readBytes() is called, an error occurs:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "buffer" because "data" is null

UPD

```
private void register(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        var ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        var client = ssc.accept();
        client.configureBlocking(false);
        SelectionKey clientKey = client.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        clientKey.attach(new ClientData());
    }
private void readBytes(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        SelectionKey clientKey = client.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        var data = (ClientData) clientKey.attachment();
        client.read(data.buffer);
    }
```

Comment: `register()` returns a *new* key, and you are throwing it away. Doing things with the old key after that is futile. Your revised `readBytes()` method registers *without* an attachment and then expects to find one. This doesn’t make sense. You would find life easier if you passed the attachment to the register method each time, and didn’t throw the result away. If you just want to switch the interestOps, use the method provided, instead of re-registering.

Comment: But in fact this isn’t the correct way to handle OP_WRITE. When you want to write, just write, and only use OP_WRITE if you happen to get a short write, to tell you when next you can write.

Comment: @close-voter No further ‘details or clarity’ are required. Don’t CV indiscriminately.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering stems from the register method. When you register the client channel with the selector for OP_READ operation, you attach an instance of ClientData to the SelectionKey that is returned by the register method. However, it seems like the register method is attaching ClientData to the wrong key.

The key passed to the register method is the server's SelectionKey (used for accepting connections), not the client's SelectionKey (used for read/write operations). When you call client.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ);, it actually returns a new SelectionKey associated with the client, to which you should attach the ClientData.

Here's a corrected version of your register method:

```
private void register(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    var ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
    var client = ssc.accept();
    client.configureBlocking(false);
    // Corrected: Attach ClientData to the client's key, not the server's key
    SelectionKey clientKey = client.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    clientKey.attach(new ClientData());
}
```

This modification should ensure that each client's SelectionKey has its own ClientData attached. Now, when readBytes method is called, it should be able to retrieve the ClientData without throwing a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I get the client key without the register method?

Comment: I changed the methods (I attached the code to the question) but still gives the same error

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry :/